# Trouble adding element to the rear of the queue using linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

i am trying to execute this queue program by using linked list implementations but it is returning me a NullPointerException error on pop() method. The program is neither adding elements nor deleting elements from the queue. I don't know what I did wrong. Please help me !!!!!!!!!

```
 public class Node {
public int data;
public Node next;
public Node(int d){
 d = data;
   }
public void printNode(){
 System.out.println(" { " + data + " } ");
     }
     }
 import java.util.*;
public class queue {

public Node front;
public Node rear;
public int size;

public queue(){
    front = null;
    rear = null;
    size = 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return front == null;
}
public void enqueue(int data){
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (isEmpty())
        newNode = front ;
    else
    rear.next = newNode;
    newNode = rear;
}

public int pop (){
    int temp = front.data;
    if (front.next == null)
        rear =null;
    front = front.next;
    return temp;
}

public int peek(){
    return front.data;
}

public int size(){
    Node current = front;
    while (current != null){
        current = current.next;
    size ++;
    }
    return size;
}

public void printList(){
    Node current = front;
    while(current != null){
        current.printNode();
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");        
   }
 }

    public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    queue list = new queue();
    System.out.println("add elements to the rear: " );
    list.enqueue(5);
    list.enqueue(6);
    list.printList();

    System.out.println("delete elements from the front: ");
    list.pop();
    list.printList();

    System.out.println("the size is : " + list.size());
}
```

}

Comment: Calling 'pop' (dequeue) before enqueueing any items should probably throw an IllegalStateException.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will suggest you to indent properly your code and to follow the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

You have some errors in your code, principally because you are using the assignment in the wrong way (see below):

- In your `Node` class you wrote this

  public Node(int d) {
      d = data;
  }

but actually what you want is this (the instance variable must be assigned not the parameter):

```
public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
}
```

- The same in your `queue` class, method `enqueue`:

`newNode = rear;` should be `rear = newNode;` and
`newNode = front;` should be `front = newNode;`

I actually didn't check for functional errors but, at least the test case, seems to work properly.

Hope this was useful!

Comment: I am very sorry for not putting my codes into the right format. I will do better next time. I fixed these two places you mentioned but it still did not work.

Comment: I forgot that you should also change `newNode = front;` in `front = newNode;`. This should fix your program.

Comment: @user2892181 Did you fix your problem?